# Magento checkout order review step,click on edit cart button losses all the checkout details and to do checkout i have to fill all the details again

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

I am using Magento default checkout for a website every things are just working fine, but when i do start checkout and go to step 6 which is "Review Order" step and click on edit cart button, it's redirect to cart page, where i can edit my cart, but to place the order i have to go through all the checkout steps again,which is really frustrating. 
It should not be to go through all the steps instead of there, it should directly go to step 6 which is "Review Order" step where i was left it.

Comment: Usually the quantity update button is only in the cart, and you cannot change the quantity on the review step of the checkout. Easiest way will be to disable/remove the editing in the review order step.

Comment: Thanks Darin for your response.